# No se logra el render de un componente en VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente componente en VueJS, el cual declaro antes de la instancia de Vue

```
Vue.component('list', {
    template: `
                <div>
                  <ul>
                  <li v-for="dato in datos">
                    <span v-if="dato.id <= 3">{{ dato.title }}</span>
                    <span v-else>
                     {{ dato.title }}
                    </span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
               </div>
               `
  })
```

El cual quiero invocar en mi HTML, de esta manera

```
<list></list>
```

Pero desde la consola recibo este error

> "[Vue warn]: Property or method "datos" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in
>
> ---> 
> "

No logro comprender como resolver el problema, encontré en un foro que había que englobar toda la información dentro de un único elemento `root` y la recomendación era un `div` pero aún así me marca error

Comment: Falta declarar `data()` dentro del componente. a primera vista deberá crear un atributo  `datos` dentro de `data()`

Comment: O puedes hacerlo en la instancia y pasarlo al componente cuando lo invocas, es decir la declaracion de ´datos´

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error aparece porque `datos` no existe dentro del componente.

Si los datos se pueden almacenar directamente dentro del componente esto puede ser una alternativa:

```
Vue.component('list', {
  data () {
    return {
      // datos se encuentra dentro del componente
      datos: [ 
        {id: 1, title: 'titulo 1'},
        {id: 2, title: 'titulo 2'},
        {id: 3, title: 'titulo 3'},
    ]
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="dato in datos">
          <span v-if="dato.id <= 3">{{ dato.title }}</span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ dato.title }}
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    `
  })

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <list></list>
</div>
```

O si por el contrario los datos están en un componente "padre", puedes pasar los datos utilizando `props`:

**JS**

```
Vue.component('list', {
  props: ['datos'], // datos es pasado a través de este atributo 
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="dato in datos">
          <span v-if="dato.id <= 3">{{ dato.title }}</span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ dato.title }}
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    `
  })

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      datos: [
        {id: 1, title: 'titulo 1'},
        {id: 2, title: 'titulo 2'},
        {id: 3, title: 'titulo 3'},
    ]
    }
  },  
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <list :datos="datos"></list>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias quedó muy bien